# erro: EOF when reading a line

Tags: python, algoritmo

Preciso arredondar as notas para o próximo múltiplo de 5, se for maior que 38 e a diferença for menor que 3. Porém, quando estou vou submeter o código me d[e o erro:

> EOF when reading a line

O que estou fazendo errado?

```
def gradingStudents(grades):
    n = int(input('alunos: '))

    for i in range(n):
        if grades[i] < 38:
            grades[i] += 0
        elif grades[i] % 5 == 3:
            grades[i] += 2
        elif grades[i] % 5 == 4:
            grades[i] += 1
    return grades

print(gradingStudents([73, 67, 38, 33]))
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Não faz sentido perguntar o número de alunos, você já sabe com a lista sendo enviada, basta pedir o tamanho da lista para usar com a função [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len). Mesmo pedindo para o usuário digitar manualmente, se digitar o tamanho correto não é para dar erro. Mão verifiquei se o resto do algoritmo está certo porque a pergunta não é sobre isto e porque o enunciado, na forma postada, está confuso.

```
def gradingStudents(grades):
    n = len(grades)
    for i in range(n):
        if grades[i] < 38:
            grades[i] += 0
        elif grades[i] % 5 == 3:
            grades[i] += 2
        elif grades[i] % 5 == 4:
            grades[i] += 1
    return grades

print(gradingStudents([73, 67, 38, 33]))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/fGYEl9). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vsykeihe-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/LenghtList.py).